# Using a VPS as a proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, firefox-for-android

I am trying to use my VPS running Cent OS as a proxy via SSH from my Galaxy S3 running Cyanogen Mod 9.

I can connect to my VPS using ConnectBot. In this program I sett the Port Forward to: 
Type: Local 
Source port: 8080 
Destination: localhost:80

I am using Firefox browser with the Proxy Mobile 0.0.10 add-on. In those options I change all the hosts to localhost and proxy ports to 8080.

When I try any web address they all redirect to the default Apache 2 screen on my VPS instead of passing the traffic through from the web.

What do I need to change? Is there something in my SSH settings I need to fix? Is it something on my phone? I know the proxy works as I can get it running via Firefox on my desktop.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have the proxy running on port 8080 or 80? Try changing the Port Forwarding to use the destination `localhost:8080`.